Failed to fetch FCM registration token on the VR Headset in Unity
I encountered an error while trying to fetch the FCM registration token for my VR headset. The error message is:
Fetching FCM registration token failed
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:14)

NOTE: Google Play Services are not available on my VR headset.
